# Hopf Conjecture about Curvature and Topology

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, conjectures

Hopf Conjecture states that:

> If even-dimensional manifold $M$ admit a metric of positive (non-negative) curvature then its Euler characteristic is positive (non-negative).

My question is about non-negative case. What is the meaning of non-negative Euler characteristic? I think "non-negative Euler characteristic" must be "zero Euler characteristic" or does there exist manifolds of non-negative curvature of positive and zero Euler characteristic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonnegative means $\ge 0$. Thus, one part of the conjecture reads: $K_M\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\chi(M)\ge 0$. The other part reads $K_M> 0$  $\Rightarrow$ $\chi(M)> 0$. You cannot expect  $K_M\ge 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\chi(M)= 0$ to hold. For instance, think about $S^2\times S^2$ or even $M=S^4$. Also, $K_M\ge 0$ does not imply $\chi(M)>0$. Standard examples would be $M=T^4$ and $M=S^3\times S^1$.

Comment: Isn't Hopf conjecture about special (critical) metrics (one can change the sign of curvature of special metrics locally always and make a piece of it to be flat) that the manifold admit?  So $K_{S^4}>0$.

Comment: @C.F.G: I do not understand your comment. There is nothing "special/critical" in Hopf conjectures.

Comment: Metrics that are not constructed from $K_M>0$ by flatting a piece of $M$. i.e. if $K_M>0$ then it admit $K_M\geq 0$ also. So for $S^4$ we consider that metric that is of positive curvature.

Comment: @C.F.G As I said, there are no extra assumptions besides the sign of curvature.